# Howa and where to detain relation logics between two ValueObjects

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

I have an Entity named `Event` using two ValueObjects, `EventType` and `EventCategory`. Each allowed category has a subset of allowed `EventType`.

I.E.

```
WeatherCategory =>     RainEvent
                       SunEvent
CompetitionCategory => FootbalMatch
                       TennishMatch
AnyCategory     =>     RainEvent
                       SunEvent
                       FootbalMatch
                       TennishMatch
```

of course I want to describe this relation in some way. At first I used an external `Validator` checking the validity of the relation between the two ValueObjects for the Entity. Now I need to get the set of Events according to a specific Category.

Basically, what I have is a repository contract that fetches events for me, filtering by category. Unfortunately my infrastructure does not have the category information, so I have to map the query according to a list of `EventType`s.

I'm wondering - according to ddd - if I should add mapping information between two ValueObjects into one of the twos, if I'd better add it into my Entity by leaving the two valueobjects without any relationship information or putting it in other classes (no idea about this).

Comment: Does this invariant seem to you to fit inside the EventAggregate or not? What other responsibilities has this Aggregate?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu mapping between Category and EventTypes are always the same among all the aggregates. Of course each aggregate can have a single EventCategory and EventType at the time. We could add some new category and/or event type in the future. The aggregate describes an event over the time the user could generate: making a phone call, top up its credit, data usage, etc. Each event has a description, a date, a user, an event type and a category.

Comment: How this association is managed?  Is hard-coded, i.e. an array?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu that's part the question :-) I don't know how and where to describe the relation between the two VO. Is within the aggregate a good place? That way I should place in my Repository's contract the Aggregate in order to get the mapping between the two VO.

Comment: That is not what I asked. Can the association be modified by an administrator or can be hardcoded?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your specific domain but most probable this invariant is not the responsibility of the EventAggregate.

In fact, the invariant should be enforced on a lower level: at the Value object's level, by a domain service; let's call it `EventTypeValidator`.

This Domain service can have the following form:

```
interface EventTypeValidator
{
    public function isEventTypeAllowedInCategory(string $eventCategory, string $eventType): bool;
}
```

Depending on how this association is managed, there could be more implementations. If the association is hard-coded, then the implementation could be like this:

```
//somewhere in the Infrastructure layer
class EventTypeValidatorByMap implements EventTypeValidator
{
    public function isEventTypeAllowedInCategory(string $eventCategory, string $eventType): bool
    {
        return $this->isEventInCategory('AnyCategory', $eventType) || $this->isEventInCategory($eventCategory, $eventType);
    }

    private function isEventInCategory(string $eventCategory, string $eventType): bool
    {
        $category = $this->getMap()[$eventCategory];

        return (in_array($eventType, $category));
    }

    private function getMap()
    {
        return [
            'WeatherCategory'     => [
                'RainEvent',
                'SunEvent',
            ],
            'CompetitionCategory' => [
                'FootbalMatch',
                'TennishMatch',
            ],
            'AnyCategory'         => [
                'RainEvent',
                'SunEvent',
                'FootbalMatch',
                'TennishMatch',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if the association is managed in a database, in another bounded context for example, the domain service could look like this:

```
//somewhere in the Infrastructure layer
class EventTypeValidatorByDatabase implements EventTypeValidator
{
    //...
    // the database PDO get's injected in the constructor

    public function isEventTypeAllowedInCategory(string $eventCategory, string $eventType): bool
    {
       //create a query that returns true if the $eventType is allowed to be in $eventCategory and false otherwise
    }
}
```

There are at least two designs regarding the value objects: with two separate value objects and with a single value object.

**I you want to have two value objects for the type and the category:**

In the Application layer, before the EventAggregate is called, the Domain service is called to validate the association that came from the UI:

```
class SomeApplicationService
{
    /** @var  EventTypeValidator */
    private $eventTypeValidator;

    public function __construct(EventTypeValidator $eventTypeValidator)
    {
        //the concrete class is resolved by the Dependency injection container
        $this->eventTypeValidator = $eventTypeValidator;
    }

    public function createAnEvent(string $eventId, string $eventCategory, string $eventType)
    {
        if(!$this->eventTypeValidator->isEventTypeAllowedInCategory($eventCategory, $eventType)){
            throw new \Exception(sprintf("Event type %s may not be in the category %s", $eventType, $eventCategory));
        }

        $event = new Event; //the Aggregate

        $event->create($eventId, $eventCategory, $eventType);

        $this->repository->persistEvent($event);
    }
}
```

**If the Event type and category are implemented as a single Value object**, i.e.

```
class CategorisedEventType
{
    /** @var string */
    private $eventCategory;

    /** @var string */
    private $eventType;

    public function __construct(string $eventCategory, string $eventType)
    {
        $this->eventCategory = $eventCategory;
        $this->eventType = $eventType;
    }

    public function getEventCategory(): string
    {
        return $this->eventCategory;
    }

    public function getEventType(): string
    {
        return $this->eventType;
    }
}
```

then this validation can be extracted in a `Factory`, by injecting the `EventTypeValidator` domain service, like this:

```
//defined in the Domain layer
class CategorisedEventTypeFactory
{
    /** @var  EventTypeValidator */
    private $eventTypeValidator;

    public function __construct(EventTypeValidator $eventTypeValidator)
    {
        $this->eventTypeValidator = $eventTypeValidator;
    }

    public function factory(string $eventCategory, string $eventType): CategorisedEventType
    {
        if(!$this->eventTypeValidator->isEventTypeAllowedInCategory($eventCategory, $eventType))
        {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf("Event type %s may not be in the category %s", $eventType, $eventCategory));
        }

        return new CategorisedEventType($eventCategory, $eventType);

    }
}
```

Then, the Application service could look like this:

```
class SomeApplicationService
{
    /** @var  CategorisedEventTypeFactory */
    private $eventTypeFactory;

    public function __construct(CategorisedEventTypeFactory $eventTypeFactory)
    {
        $this->eventTypeFactory = $eventTypeFactory;
    }

    public function createAnEvent(string $eventId, string $eventCategory, string $eventType)
    {
        $eventTypeAndCategory = $this->eventTypeFactory->factory($eventCategory, $eventType);

        $event = new Event; //the Aggregate

        $event->create($eventId, $eventTypeAndCategory);

        $this->repository->persistEvent($event);
    }
}
```

I prefer the design with a single Value object and a `Factory` as it moves the domain logic into the domain layer.

Things could be simplified if by getting rid of the `EventTypeValidator` interface and using only the concrete class, if the other implementations are not applicable (i.e. the association it is always hard-coded).

Comment: nice answer! But imagine this scenario: I have to expose a use case to find Event filtered by category. Unfortunately, the persistence only detains the `eventType`, hence I need the relation information about category and event  somewhere. The `CategorisedEventTypeFactory` solution you mentioned could expose this kind of information, but I was wondering if this is best practice or I'm doing it the dirty way

Comment: @Bertuz You said that you `have an Entity named Event using two ValueObjects, EventType and EventCategory`. This means that every Event from the repository has a Category assigned. Filtering should be simple. Are you saying that in fact your Events don't have the category directly asociated to them?

Comment: by the domain point of view: yes. By the persistence point of view: no. The database has events without the category stored. That's why I need the mapping information when retrieving data from the repository. Actually the repository is a RESTful service I can't touch

Comment: @Bertuz DDD is more focused on the Validation part (not allowing the Event getting into an invalid state), not on querying; this is also how my answer is focused. However, I can guide you to solve this problem also.

Comment: @Bertuz so, the solution that works best in your case with the Validation and the Querying is to have a single value object that contain the event type and the event category, like the one in my answer: `CategorisedEventType`

Comment: @Bertuz in this case, you have both the event type and the event category in the persistence (database) for each Event entity

Comment: Let's put it simply: according to an hexagonal architecture and trying to be stick to DDD principles: is it OK putting a `getCategoryEventTypesRelations` method inside a `CategorisedEventType` or am I breaking some principle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162807/discussion-between-constantin-galbenu-and-bertuz).

Comment: @Bertuz Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162807/discussion-between-constantin-galbenu-and-bertuz).